# Push different branch to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

Just finised work on my `other` branch. Now I need to test that this works on Heroku before I merge with the `master` branch.

Is it possible to push the `other` branch to Heroku and it replace the contents of my last push which was from the `master` branch?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Yes, pushing to a branch named differently that your current one is possible using the syntax:

```
git push heroku other:master
```

This tells Git to push the contents of your `other` branch to the `master` branch on the `heroku` remote. Keep in mind that you may have to force push if there are commits on `heroku/master` that don't appear in your `other` branch.

For more information have a look at the [documentation of the `<refspec>` option](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to `git push`.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
git push -f heroku otherBranch:master
```

> The -f (force flag) is recommended in order to avoid conflicts with other developers’ pushes. Since you are not using Git for your revision control, but as a transport only, using the force flag is a reasonable practice.

source :- [offical docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote)